# Add multiple Excel charts into Word using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I am adding multiple histograms into word automatically using C#, I created a loop and in each iteration the program adds one chart in a separate page. The code is fine however for some reason the Excel crashes and the program stops.

Any advice ?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> unique_year_item in uniqe_years_dic)
{


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para_fig4 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
    styleHeading2 = "Heading 2";
    para_fig3.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading2);
    para_fig3.Range.Text = "Reports by Zone per for year "+ unique_year_item.Key.ToString() ;
    para_fig3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();


         Dictionary<string, int> compliants_by_zone_per_year = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Global.sub_table.Count(); i++)
    {

        DateTime d =DateTime.Parse(Global.sub_table[i][2]); 

        if(unique_year_item.Key == d.Year)
        {
        string zone_key = Global.sub_table[i][1] + Global.sub_table[i][0];

        if (!compliants_by_zone_per_year.ContainsKey(zone_key))
            compliants_by_zone_per_year.Add(zone_key, 1);
        else
            compliants_by_zone_per_year[zone_key] += 1;
        }
    }

    object oRng_fig_4 = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape wrdInlineShape_fig4 = document.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(classtype, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, oRng_fig_4);
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    if (wrdInlineShape_fig4.OLEFormat.ProgID == "Excel.Chart.8")
    {
        // Word doesn't keep all of its embedded objects in the running state all the time.
        // In order to access the interface you first have to ensure the object is in the running state,
        // ie: OLEFormat.Activate() (or something)
       object verb = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOLEVerb.wdOLEVerbHide;
   wrdInlineShape_fig4.OLEFormat.DoVerb(ref verb);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook obook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)wrdInlineShape_fig4.OLEFormat.Object;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)obook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 4; c++)
            {
                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, c]).Value = "";
                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, c]).Value = "";
            }
        }


        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value = "Zone name";
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 2]).Value = "Number of Comp.";
        int cell_index = 2;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in compliants_by_zone_per_year)
        {
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[cell_index, 1]).Value = Global.dictionary_zone_name_ID[item.Key];// rn.Next(10, 50);
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[cell_index, 2]).Value = item.Value;
            cell_index++;
        }

        wrdInlineShape_fig4.Width = 400;
        wrdInlineShape_fig4.Height = 450;

        obook.ActiveChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlBarClustered;


        obook.ActiveChart.HasTitle = true;
        obook.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Reports by Zone per for year " + unique_year_item.Key.ToString();
        obook.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Shadow = true;
        obook.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Border.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series oSeries;
        oSeries = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series)obook.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1);


        obook.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(sheet.get_Range("A:A", "B:B"));


       wrdInlineShape_fig4.ConvertToShape();               


        document.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);

    }


 }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and see if Excel crashes at a specific point in your code.

Comment: I think the problem not in the Excel itself. The code above dose not produce regular behavior. Some times I see the Excel runs in the screen and the program returns one of the following errors: 

1- (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
2- Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Comment: Maybe this can help http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2012/09/28/Office-Interop-and-Call-was-rejected-by-callee.aspx

Comment: This link is very useful. Now I understand the problem.
Also, tracking the problem mentioned in the link above I found more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228772(v=vs.110).aspx   

I also added Thread.Sleep(xxx) and this solved the problem. Not ideal solution but at least the program is running.